# servlet which can call a method and pass the value extracted from the web request

Tags: java, servlets

i have a question on how a servlet call a method and pass the value extracted from the web request.  A scenario in which a web request is processed in a web request, i need to call a method and pass in the values extracted from the web request. When the method returns a value, send the value in the web response. thanks

Comment: Please re-read your question, and ask yourself if you're able to understand what it means.

Comment: I have created a serlvet, jsp and a java class. When the parameters are passed from the jsp to the servlet, the servlet must call the method in the java class that returns a value. How can i go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right you need something like this:

```
public class MyNewServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String param = request.getParameter("paramname");
        String result = MyBusinessClass.myBusinessMethod(param);
        response.getWriter().append("The answer is: " + result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When request comes from browser, it will first read web.xml and call service method of appropriate servlet. Then service method decide to call doPost or doGet method on the basis of request. Once you get parameter , you need to create object of requestDispatcher and call forward method which will send your response.